# Reading int As Separate Digits

Tags: c++, arrays, string, loops, int

I have numbers in a text file some negative, all contain decimal, I have managed to read them and convert them to integers to display;

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {



        std::string str = &(cmemblock[0]); //cmemblock is the .txt file
        std::istringstream iss(str);
        std::vector<int> numbers;
        int number;
        while (iss >> number) {
            numbers.push_back(number);  // collect inputs

            cout << number << endl; //Displays Stored Value
            }





        if (!iss.eof()) {
            cout << "Blank Space"<<endl; //Error message to detect blank space
        }
    }
```

I need help on creating a loop to read each each character, for example if the 1st line is '-0.009876', each value should be read separately, '-',  '0'  '.'  and so on. The reason for this is because the number is to be represented in morse code, which has already been set up in an array, so I need the individual number to allocate each digit to its specified morse code.

Comment: Why not just loop/iterate over each individual character of the string using the string's `[]` operator?

Comment: Do you expect the numbers in unusual format? such as 10E+3?

Comment: @R Sahu No, it should be as a whole numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've posted, I wouldn't bother with any local numeric conversion. I would simply read in the text file and iterate across each character individually, mapping it to your morse code mapping array. If you need to use a given number as an index into your mapping array, you can convert it from a char into an int value by "subtracting" '0' from it, eg, assuming a loop using charPosition as the outermost loop index through the string..

```
//...omitting other fairly obvious loop code
// with str holding '-0.009776'

if (isdigit(str[charPosition]))
{
   int index = str[charPosition] - '0';
   // index into 0-based array of presumed morse code mapping values
   morseValue = morseMap[index];
}
```

Comment: This code gave me the idea I needed, got it! Great answer thanks